# Using Apache Spark in IntelliJ Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I try to run Apache Spark 1.6.3 with Scala 2.10.5 in IntelliJ 2016.3 using the most recent Scala-Plugin. The project is a maven project.

If I try to create a new SparkContext using :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf.setAppName("Spark-Scala-Demo").setMaster("local[*]"))
```

I get

```
17/01/16 14:05:28 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.getRpcEnvFactory(RpcEnv.scala:41)
```

The code runs fine both in IntelliJs scala console as well as in a normal class defining a main-method.

So what is different in a scala worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the beginning of the worksheet: `import org.apache.spark.rpc.netty`

Comment: doesn't help.. same exception